# Scraping web data using asynchronous request

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, asynchronous

I've written a script using python to grab different categories from a webpage. I used "grequests" in my scraper to perform the activity. My intention here was to perform the action swiftly making asynchronous HTTP requests. My scraper is running flawlessly and collecting data as it should. However, in case of performance, I'm not sure it is giving the optimum. Any suggestion to make it better will be highly appreciated.

```
import grequests ; from lxml import html

main_link = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"

def toscrape_scraper(item_link):
    storage = [item_link]      # Depositing link as a list
    response = (grequests.get(req) for req in storage)
    for req in grequests.map(response):                #Sending requests
        tree = html.fromstring(req.text)
        for titles in tree.cssselect("span.tag-item a.tag"):
            grabbing_docs(main_link + titles.attrib['href'])

def grabbing_docs(base_link):
    vault = [base_link]          # Storing links as a list
    res = (grequests.get(req) for req in vault)
    for hreq in grequests.map(res):               #Sending requests
        root = html.fromstring(hreq.text)
        for soups in root.cssselect("div.quote"):
            quote = soups.cssselect("span.text")[0].text
            author = soups.cssselect("small.author")[0].text
            print(quote, author)

    next_page = root.cssselect("li.next a")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect("li.next a") else ""
    if next_page:
        page_link = main_link + next_page
        grabbing_docs(page_link)  #Reusing the newly collected paginated links

toscrape_scraper(main_link)
```

Comment: Are you certain that you won't request a link (through `grabbing_docs(link)`) more than once in the current implementation? If that were to happen, you could enter a cycle.